# List Variable in Library Causes run time error, why?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, stdlist

OK folks.  I have fixed the error by moving the variable definition, but I do not understand why there is a problem.
Simplified Background: I have an object and I want to track all instances of that object in a list, so I simply created a List<> static member of the class.  Below was a simple representation that allowed me to play with it.  If I have the line marked as "this line" in the static library.  I get a run time error.  The object is defined in a header file and is the same header file in both places.  If I move "this line" to the code in my final application and it works.... Why?  I just don't understand why it is different.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class someobject
   {
   public:
      someobject()
         {
         // do some stuff.
         theStaticList.push_back(this);
         }

      void func()
         {
         printf("Made it!!\n");
         }
   static list<someobject*> theStaticList;
   };

list<someobject*> someobject::theStaticList;    //*** This line


someobject global;

int main()
{
   someobject initial;

   initial.func();
   global.func();

   list<someobject*>::iterator iter;

   printf("\n\nLoop the Static List\n");

   for (iter = someobject::theStaticList.begin(); iter != someobject::theStaticList.end  ();       iter++)
       (*iter)->func();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put that line in a header file, then include the header into two or more source files, you're defining the list object in each source file where the header gets included.

This violates the one definition rule, so the linker will quite rightly give you an error when you do it.

You want to define the object in *one* (and only one) source file. For a library, that should be some object file in the library, not the user's source file though (at least as a general rule).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear when I simplified it. When you put the static item in the herader, you also have to have the additional line to define the static varaible. It is defined in the one of the CPP files. When I do that in the a library CPP file, I get a run time crash. I can not try and catch or anything on creation of the global variable. If I move that same line from a CPP file in the library to a CPP file in my EXE project, it works. The error has nothing to do with redefinition as far as I understand, but again if understood it, I would not have posted this.